If $D$ is Cartier and $D_{\overline{k}}$ is $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$-invariant, is it also Cartier?
Suppose we have a proper scheme (or even a variety) $X$ over a non-closed field $k$. Take a ($\mathbb{Q}$-)Cartier divisor on $X$ such that $D_{\overline{k}}$ is $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$-invariant. Is it true that $D_{\overline{k}}$ is again ($\mathbb{Q}$)-Cartier?
In general taking the algebraic closure does not preserve ($\mathbb{Q}$-)factoriality. But if you take the G-action on $Div(X_{\overline{k}})$ intuitively it is clear to me that it should respect the div operator, but I do not know how to write it down correctly.
